# add multiple polygons to rCharts leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson, rcharts, rjsonio

When I try to add more than one polygon to a leaflet map with `rCharts` using the `map$geoJson()` function, only the last polygon appears on the map. The other ones are not displayed. Any idea on what I can do to add more than one polygon to my map? Below you can see a detailed description of what I did:

**1. I am querying a postgis DB to get my polygons and as a result I get the code of a single polygon as a GeoJSON that looks approximately like this:**

```
"{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[16.644953973395001,48.142664957703971], ...[16.644439684506018,48.143173899704649],[16.644953973395001,48.142664957703971]]]}"
```

In sum I have 81 polygons and I want to display them on a leaflet map. I am using the rCharts package for this purpose.

**2. As a next step I convert them with the package `RJSONIO` using the `fromJSON` function. Then the code of a single polygons looks approximately like this:**

```
    $type
[1] "Polygon"

$coordinates
$coordinates[[1]]
$coordinates[[1]][[1]]
[1] 16.66885 48.42283

$coordinates[[1]][[2]]
[1] 16.66196 48.42634

$coordinates[[1]][[3]]
[1] 16.65877 48.42876

.
.
.

$coordinates[[1]][[62]]
[1] 16.67115 48.42179

$coordinates[[1]][[63]]
[1] 16.66885 48.42283
```

**3. As the last step I create a leaflet map and add the polygons with the `map$geoJson` function:**

```
map <- Leaflet$new()
map$tileLayer(provider = 'Stamen.TonerLite')

map$setView(c(48.42283, 16.66885), zoom = 10)
map$enablePopover(TRUE)
map$geoJson(polygon1)
map$geoJson(polygon2)
map$geoJson(polygon3)
map$geoJson(polygon4)
map$fullScreen(TRUE)
map$set(width = 800, height = 600)
map
```

With this method, only the last polygon (polygon4) is being display on the map, the other ones dont show up. Any suggestions on how to make them appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct a *single* geoJSON object with all your polygons in and add that. See here:

https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/leaflet/examples/example10.R

Note the json is a FeatureCollection with geometry-type Polygon features. Build that string from your polygon coordinates and add.

Comment: This is the recommended approach. I believe LeafletJS allows one to add simple geometries one at a time, but I have not exposed that in the rCharts binding. So `geoJSON` is the way to go.

Comment: Multiple geoJSON layers in rCharts would be handy, but eventually one has to bite the bullet and realise one may as well write the JS oneself.

Comment: That is True. There has to be a balance.

Comment: And how is it possible to write a geoJson from multiple datasets, and displaying points and polygons on it?